# Calculate whether you can jump from one platform to another

Tags: c++, physics

I need some kind of formula that will help me connect two platforms that are reachable to each other by jump. I am working on a pathfinding implementation for a 2D platformer and preprocessing the map has been the bane of my existence. Here are some of the physics involved in this platformer:

> fallSpeed = 670 px/s (Maximum speed falling in the downwards direction)

> gravityAcc = 2000 px/s^2

> jumpSpeed = 555 px/s (velocity component along the y-axis)

> walkSpeed = 125 px/s (Base speed of a character)

Comment: You should be able to get the maximum height easily, should be formulas for that in classical physics texts. I think there is less chance for premade closed form formulas for general jumps, maybe you can get something from projectile formulas, but they usually do not include max fall speed.

Comment: If feasible, perhaps it's easier for the predecessor to infer connections by *simulating* the jump from the edges (and several other points) of the platform, with some reasonable cutoff (e.g. within some box), and then check for collisions. I.e., have the game partially play out and check what happens, rather then calculate trajectories. The cutoff box could, say, prevent the weird edge cases, e.g. you may not want to connect the starting platform with another platform that's 15 screens down, that you happen to fall on.